# What emulators are used with Emulation Station?

Tags: raspbian, emulation

I've compiled EmulationStation from source rather than download the RetroPie disk image. I've followed [these instructions here](http://www.emulationstation.org/gettingstarted.html#install_rpi_standalone). However, when I attempt to play a rom, EmulationStation errors out with a

> retroarch not found

error. **Does this mean I need to install the emulators as well?**

Where should I download the emulators? There's only a handful in the Pi Store and I can't find a n64, snes or nes emulator anywhere.

**What are the emulators retro pie use?**

I only want to emulate:

- n64
- snes
- nes
- gameboy advance

Where do I find this software?

The reason I've compiled Emulation from source manually for 2 reasons::

**1) Already have a bunch of projects on my Pi and I only have 1 micro sd card**

**2) I only want to play a few systems, not the whole extensive list of consoles that come with retro pie.**